# Specifying comma separated value in IN clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written the following PL/SQL code in Oracle:

```
declare
    l_today date := sysdate;
    company varchar2(30):='info'; 
    howmany     INTEGER;
    params varchar2(10000):= 'color-1,color-2';

begin
    select count(*) into howmany from toys where colour 
IN (
   'color-1'
    );    
dbms_output.put_line (howmany);
    dbms_output.put_line (params);

exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
```

I want to make the select clause inside begin dynamic by specifying the list for IN clause in a variable. In the above params is a comma seperated string and I want to do in params. I tried some ways but couldn't achieve it. Looks like there is no easy way to do it.
Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

I tried using some split and in_list function I came across on some websites, but they all gave error.
I want to use this functionality where I have a list of 20 strings to be used. Either I can hardcode them into the in-clause or make a variable and then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match on sub-strings (including the surrounding delimiters so that you match complete terms):

```sql
declare
  howmany INTEGER;
  params  varchar2(10000) := 'color-1,color-2';
begin
  select count(*)
  into   howmany
  from   toys
  where  ',' || params || ',' LIKE '%,' || colour || ',%';
  dbms_output.put_line (howmany);
  dbms_output.put_line (params);
end;
/
```

or you can create a collection data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

and then use it in the filter:

```sql
declare
  howmany INTEGER;
  params  string_list := string_list('color-1', 'color-2');
begin
  select count(*)
  into   howmany
  from   toys
  where  colour MEMBER OF params;
  dbms_output.put_line (howmany);
  FOR i IN 1 .. params.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line (params(i));
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

*Note: catching `OTHERS` is considered bad practice as it will hide all exceptions. It is better practice to catch specific exceptions that you expect to be raised and then unexpected exceptions will cause the code to fail and can be debugged.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Xk4GGG8)

Answer (score 0):

Use you favourite [csv-to-rows conversion](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database) method to turn the list into a series of rows. Then check the column is `in` these rows

For example:

```
create table toys (
  color varchar2(10)
);

insert into toys values ( 'color-1' );
insert into toys values ( 'color-1' );
insert into toys values ( 'color-2' );
insert into toys values ( 'color-3' );

var in_list varchar2(100)
exec :in_list := 'color-1,color-2';

select * from toys
where  color in (
  select regexp_substr ( :in_list, '[^,]+', 1, level )
  from   dual
  connect by level <= length ( :in_list ) - length ( replace ( :in_list, ',' ) ) + 1
);

COLOR     
----------
color-1
color-1
color-2
```

Comment: Thanks. But isn't that a lot of complex code for achieving such a simple thing?

Comment: If you're on an up-to-date patch of 19c you could create a table macro to hide the logic https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database#reusable-csv-rows-function. You need to use some form of CSV-to-rows conversion though